# Difference between incomplete gamma function and factorial

Tags: analysis

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider (for real $x$)
$$
f_n(x) = |\Gamma(n+1,ix)| - n!
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function. Plotting $f_n(x)$ for various $n$ it seems that there is some $a > 0$ such that $f_n(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in (-a,a)$ if and only if $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$ or $n \equiv 0 \mod 4$. In the former case, it appears that $a \approx 1.7$ gives the largest such interval, and in the latter case it looks like $a \approx 3.3$.

Do these observations hold in general? If so, can more precise values for $a$ be obtained?

Comment: What does precisely represent $ |\Gamma(n+1,ix)|$

Comment: The absolute value of the incomplete gamma function with first argument a positive integer and second argument a purely imaginary number.